# How to add react style no-repeat

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript

I'm using react.
I've added a no-repeat style to backgroundImage, but the image doesn't show up.
when I remove the no-repeat, the image shows up.

```
    <div
      style={{
        position: 'relative',
        width: '580px',
        height: '460px',
        marginRight: '300px',
        marginBottom: '20px',
        marginLeft: '80px',
        backgroundImage: `url(${url}) no-repeat 50% 50%`,
      }}
    >
```

Answer (score 2):

The css `background-image` does not support repeat/no-repeat. You should use the `background-repeat` property.

```
backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat"
```

You could also use the css `background` shorthand to define multiple background style properties (in any order).

```
background: "no-repeat center url(./lolcat.png)"
```

Comment: 50% Where should I put the 50%?

Comment: You can use `background-position: 50% 50%;` or it can be part of the `background` shorthand property.